# Thread-safety issue for servlet

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety

I recently read an article about [writing thread-safe servlets](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0712-threadsafe.html?page=4), and I learned that it is unsafe to make use of a servlet's member fields in `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods since it is likely that the single instance of servlet handles two separate requests with two threads, meaning the member variables are shared resource. I am wondering if I have to worry about thread-safety on servlet dependencies. In my application design, the servlet will make a service call to a POJO service handler, and I am thinking of a single dependency injection from Spring(using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it is likely that the single instance of servlet handles two separate requests with two threads" -- it is not only likely, it is exactly how servlets work inside servlet container. There is one servlet instance per `servlet` declaration in web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being thread-safe is exactly the reason why you have the 'request' scope. Making things thread-safe is much harder than it looks. But in a common web scenario you can push the problem all the way down to:

- database, which gives you atomicity and thread safety for free;
- stateless services, which are, by definition, thread-safe (there is no state that could be broken).

So just:

- make your daos stateless,
- make your services stateless,
- if you need some temporary state, use request-scoped beans.

getBean() is thread-safe, so you can just pluck your pojo services and use them, as long as you do not store them as servlet attributes.

In such case your only problems are:

- beans living in session;
- custom caches;
- complicated custom application logic;

Beans living in sessions can be made immutable (unless points 2 or 3 also apply). Custom caches can usually be skipped (In many cases they do not make things faster anyway - really! Unless you can prove them useful by profiling, throw them away). This leaves us with number 3: complicated custom application logic. And this one is tricky.

Anyway, since such application logic is inherently complicated, being thread-safe is probably the least of our worries.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you have to worry about it on the POJO as well.  It's a member variable.  Make the service threadsafe.